# Facing 'Permission ' error while trying to execute Stored Procedure published through SQL CLR c# stored procedure

Tags: c#, visual-studio, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

Hope you're doing well.

I've created a Stored procedure using `SQL CLR c# stored procedure` in Visual studio 2017 and I've published it in `MSSQL server` . Now I can see my Stored procedure but I face this error when I want to execute the procedure.
  The error is :

```
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Procedure cust_diff, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 2]
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or 
 aggregate "cust_diff": 
 System.Security.SecurityException: 
 System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission
 System.Security.SecurityException: 
at LevenshteinDistance.cust_diff()
```

I've added these two at the beginning of my code in C#

```
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Permissions;
```

and also this is part of my code that I create the procedure

```
 [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
 [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Assert, Unrestricted = true)]
 public static void cust_diff()
 {

    // Put your code here
    LevenshteinDistance ld = new LevenshteinDistance();
    ld.Method1();
 }
```

but despite using these two , I cannot execute my Procedure in SSMS.
I was wondering if you could help me out with this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: right click on stored procedure in SSMS and check the credentials.  The credentials need to match the login credentials using SSMS.  Normally the stored procedure would start with "db".

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for your comment .I was wondering if you could explain a little bit more . For example where can I find The procedure credential? and how is it supposed to be the same as the login credential ? Thanks a lot . I have not heard about procedure credential before .

Comment: Right click on the procedure will show credentials.  You also need to check the credentials for each user/group in the database.  You should be using the same credentials for c# connection string as the login using SSMS.  The best way is to use a Windows credentials and create a Group Account.  Then add all users to the windows group account which will have all users with the same access to the database and allow remote connections to database.

Comment: @jdweng this is the format through which we are trying to connect to The MSSQL server Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True; is this a correct way to connect ? the problem is that i can not find the word 'credential' when I right click on my stored procedure

Comment: @jdweng another thing is we are using SA login to connect to  SQL server. I mean SYSADMIN . The user has all privileges.

Comment: Trusted Connection true is using Windows credentials of user which should be a group account.  What are the credentials in the login window of SSMS?  On the stored procedure you would see the owner of the procedure and the group read/write permissions.

Comment: You should not be using an ADMIN account for simple read/write to database so all users can access data.  Admin login should be reserved for special privileges  I suspect you created the stored procedure as an Admin and then login as a user and tried to use procedure from SSMS.  Some stored procedures should have special credentials to prevent users from deleting but must have standard users read/execute access.   Then users should also be allowed to create their own stored procedures.  Normally the users stored procedures start with 'db'.